# anchor tags and dynamic views in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm taking my first steps with angular, looks promising but i have some issues, hope someone can help.

i have a long html page divided to sections
each section is an anchor tag, you can navigate to it from top menu.
the content in each section changes according to some parameters the user selects.
so the 3rd section's content for instance can be different(template) each time.

my problem:
i would like to dynamically load views into the section.
as i understand it i have only one ng-view that corresponds to specific rout.
how can i load a view (template+controller) dynamically as the user slides to the anchor tag?

thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about user set parameters and how they are bound to scope model and provide some sample code.

Comment: can use directive to return proper `ng-include` or `templateURL`. Very hard to answer based on `general concept`

Comment: it's a general concept, i don't have a code (yet), i assume the app-controller will mange the "views exchange" lats say user can choose between 'simple', 'medium' and 'advanced' options. according to his selection a 'subview' changes his template and controller dynamically to corresponding "views" in some other section (anchor) on page

Comment: if you haven't been through the tutorial on docs site step by step, suggest doing that. Once you get something started with your app and run into issue, create a demo in plunker. Gneral concepts are very difficult to help with without some context in code

Comment: OK, i will try to do so, BTW i read the documentation and a lot of blogs but could not find an answer. thanks for the meantime

Comment: directive is likely what is needed